# PHP upload File not saving into upload folder

Tags: php, html

Editted

Now I am encountered another problem which is upload file is not saving into upload folder I set up.

### Below are resolved

I have been working with this simple HTML and PHP code to upload files into web server but this error is keep displaying every time I tried to upload file into the server.  File is not uploaded into server.

I am using Windows 7, IIS 7.5, PHP 5.6.2

I have already created folder for uploaded files (uploads) and I have given full control permission to all of my web server folders to IIS user.

I tried to search on the web first but I could not notice any similar problems as mine.

Here is detailed error message

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Here is my HTML script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" 
              method="post" 
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="file">
                Filename:
            </label>
            <input type="file" 
                   name="file" 
                   id="file"><br />
            <input type="submit" 
                   value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP script

```
<?php
    $my_folder = "uploads/";
    copy($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$my_folder.$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo "File uploaded.";
?>
```

Comment: IIS will throw 404 for any attempt to access a file extension it doesn't recognize, even if the file exists. You probably didn't configure PHP properly in your server.

Comment: just fixed 404 error but now I m encountering uploaded file not stored in the folder I set up

Comment: please post the directory strucutre of your project and a snapshot of the console of your browser about the network activities. Also, indicate where is the http root of your project

Comment: instead of copy, use the move_uploaded_file function. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: I switched to move_uploaded_file function, now I am having HTTP 500 internal server error... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

$my_folder = "./uploads/";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $my_folder . $_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    echo 'Received file' . $_FILES['file']['name'] . ' with size ' . $_FILES['file']['size'];
} else {
    echo 'Upload failed!';

    var_dump($_FILES['file']['error']);
}
```

Check for read/write permissions on the target folder.

PHP Manual:

- [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)
- [`Handling of File Uploads`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php), especially [`File Upload Errors`](http://php.net/manual/de/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: its not working either...
I gave full control to everyone but its not working

Comment: it echo "upload filed!"

Comment: And whats the file upload error your get? `var_dump($_FILES['file']['error']);`

Comment: Upload failed!int(6)  this is whats showing on the browser

Comment: "UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR" Missing temporary dir - http://php.net/manual/de/features.file-upload.errors.php Have you properly configured your temporary path in php.ini's file uploads section: set the "upload_tmp_dir" directive?

Comment: upload_tmp_dir = "C:\PHP\tmp  this is where I have set up for tmp folder

Comment: Is IIS configured to write to that folder? The IIS Account needs access (read, write, modify permissions). You might try "C:\WINDOWS\Temp\". Both: the temp folder and the target folder need the correct permissions.

Comment: PHP\tmp folder is set for full control to everyone.  I switched to Windows\temp\ but it still giving me the same error msg.

Comment: Hey Jens-Andre Koch!, I fixed the error msg and finally I am getting files into the upload forlder.  giving full control to everyone on my PHP folder resolved issue.  Now I have to figure out which folder must not to give out a full control to everyone.  Thanks again and have a nice day

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, i tried everything for 2 hours and finally I figured out that Read/Write permissions on the folder is the trick.